# Regex to extract substring between different starting and ending strings within HTML

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a simple scraper tool that will extract a specific URL from a webpage. The page has many URLs, but I want to get the one that ends with a specific set of characters.

For example, if somewhere in the page source there is a url that looks like this:

`source: "https://www.website.com/dog.pdf"`

I want to return `https://www.website.com/dog.pdf` without the quotes. If there is more than one match, I only want to return the first one.

So the Regex should extract everything after `source:` and up to and including the `.pdf"`

--

I've looked at other questions, but most answers refuse to provide a RegEx and instead say to use `startswith()` and `endswith()`. But since the page source could be massive, I'm worried about performance. I am new to Python, though, and perhaps I'm just not understanding how to use those methods.

Comment: Why not use the right tool for the job, an HTML parser?

Comment: @ggorlen - I'm sorry, I am using BeautifulSoup to extract the HTML, but I'm not sure how that would help with pulling out that specific instance of an element.

Comment: Using BS seems like a major improvement over regexing on the entire HTML blob to me. Once you have the text from a particular href, then you're correct that it's a pattern matching problem, but I would include a [mcve] showing a relevant snippet of the input and expected output. Is the text literally an `<a>` tag with the `source: "https..."` inside it exactly? If so, then the problem is probably a "how do I match a URL with regex", no?

Comment: @ggorlen - I'll look into the other functions BS provides. All new to me but if it can do this, I'd agree that would be a better route. In the meantime, I'll throw together an [mcve].

Comment: If you want to match source: followed by your url, perhaps try using a capturing group`source: "(http[^\s"]+\.pdf)"` https://regex101.com/r/PL3PMI/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
import re
example = '''
    source: "https://www.website.com/dog.pdf"
    source: "https://www.website.com/cat.pdf"
'''
pattern = r'"(?P<url>.+?)"'
m = re.search(pattern, example)
url = m.group('url') # result is https://www.website.com/dog.pdf
```

**UPD.**

To return the first link in double-quotes, the regular expression will look like this:

```
pattern = r'"(?P<url>https?:\/\/.+?)"'
```

If you need to find the first link in double-quotes that ends with `.pdf`, then the regular expression will be like this:

```
pattern = r'"(?P<url>https?:\/\/.+?\.pdf)"'
```

Comment: And what do you get if there are more than 1 URL in a single line?

Comment: Updated the answer. Added lazy quantifier